# How do I attach a drywall corner bead to a wood door jamb?

Tags: doors, corner-bead

I am installing a door into a wall and I do not want to have casing on the door. I want to install corner bead directly to the door jamb to create a "hidden door". It seems that typical corner bead is too small.

Comment: Is this a door opening or is it an actual door jamb installed with a physical door mounted in the jamb?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that there are two possibilities here. If the opening in the wall is just a pass through without an actual door itself then you would band the opening with drywall material and then put normal metal corner edging around the outside corners of the drywall.

[image]

On the other hand if there is a door jamb in use with an actual door then the width of the jamb wants to be equal to the stud width and then the drywall is installed out over the edge of the door jamb and finished off with an end cap type metal edging.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! J bead is something that I didn't think about.